# Windows 10: cannot use newly created user profiles

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, user-profiles

On my Windows 10 Professional workstation I have a strange problem.

Every newly created user (local or domain users) creates a new profile, but the new profile is not usable.

In detail, if I click on the start menu nothing happens (and the menu does not open), and Microsoft Store and Mail icons are with a strange blue background as you can see in the following picture:

[image]

I tried following the information at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f5bb2326-a57c-4c11-8b54-79e9b3af661d/start-menu-not-working-with-mandatory-profiles?forum=win10itprosetup without success:

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
SFC /scannow
```

Both commands executed correctly with success and with no errors.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: What happened exactly when you ran those commands what did you expect to happen.  **Update your question, provide specific detail, so we can help you**

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question: both commands exited correctly with success and with no errors.

Comment: Which means your problem isn't caused by system corruption.  This means your problem is likely caused by a third-party application that is installed.  If it was system corruption either of those commands would have repaired the corrupt system files.

Comment: Thanks. Don't you have any idea about that? I've never seen these blue icons.

Comment: One is the icon for the `Microsoft Store` UWP application, but the icon is slightly odd, but I recognize it all the same.

Comment: I suspect that you are using a corrupted system image.
Try to download a clean iso from Microsoft website by media creation tool then in-place upgrade current system, after this, create a user account to check result.